# how to call sms gateway url from biztalk server

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I need to create a BizTalk solution wherein I'll need to call an SMS gateway URL from BizTalk server. Is there a way to do this?

The URL looks like below. I only need to pass the phone_number and the text_msg parameter in doing this.

`http://111.111.1.111/sendsms.cgi?mobile_number=+6512345678&text_msg=test`

Answer (score 1):

If it is a REST API then you can use the WCF-WebHttp Adapter and pass the Phone Numbers and TExt message as variables in the URL itself.
These properties (Phone No and Text message) would need to be promoted and then will be passed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by adding an Expression shape in my orchestration and in that expression I have placed this line of code.

```
sendPort_SendSms(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = "http://111.111.1.111/api/sendsms.cgi?" + "mobile_number=" + varMobileNumber + "&" + "text_msg=" + varMessageBody;
```

I have declared my 2 parameters: `mobile_number(varMobileNumber)` and  `text_msg(varMessageBody)` as variables so I can just pass whichever value in it.

This worked like a charm.